# Entity Framework query says column not found for a column I never specified

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have the following database structure for a table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StepVariables]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [VariableId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [StepVariableId] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_StepVariables] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

My query looks like this.

```
List<StepVariable> stepVariables;

using (HHEDataContext context = new HHEDataContext("HHEDatabase"))
{
    stepVariables = (from sv in context.StepVariables
                     where sv.StepId == stepId
                     select sv).ToList();
}

return stepVariables;
```

My entity object looks like this.

```
public class StepVariable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int VariableId { get; set; }
    public int StepVariableId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

When I run this, I get the following error.

> An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
>
> {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'StepAction_Id'.
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
>   ClientConnectionId:1db1a7c4-51de-49ca-856d-3a0eab5462da
>   Error Number:207,State:1,Class:16}

Does anyone know where it is getting StepAction_ID?  Other queries in this database work just fine.

Comment: probably u have wrong EF mapping, model property `StepId` is mapped to db column `StepAction_Id`, which is not exists.

Comment: Did you post your entire CREATE TABLE statement? It looks it's missing something at the end, since it ends with comma.

Comment: Added entire ef class, and entire create statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you using a custom convention? because by default Id should be used as key, but maybe depend from the version of EF

take a look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx

anyway if you can rename your Id property, try using StepVariableId to see if the error goes away

or since you didn't posted the whole class, did you have maybe a navigable property to a StepAction instance?

Comment: I changed StepID to StepVariableID, and still get the same issue.

Comment: can you post the whole class? don't you have a property of type StepAction  there?

Comment: yes, you just posted 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int VariableId { get; set; }
    public int StepId {get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

but the problem could be on the rest of the class

Comment: Done.  I didn't add this because there was nothing else in the class.

Comment: i guess than that the problem isn't here but maybe you have another Entity (StepActin) added to the DBContext mapping, and that's the one generating the problem. Or you manually created a configuration for this map, anyway those are just guesses without knowing the code

Comment: But wouldn't that prevent any queries from running?  I have other queries that run just fine.

Comment: it depend if that queries use that entity

Comment: That was it.  Another entity was referencing this class.  I removed that reference, and it works.